Can't seem to find flaws in this proof of $\sqrt{2}$'s irrationality
A friend recently showed a proof for $\sqrt{2}$ being irrational that, despite it's apparent simplicity, I cannot seem to find anywhere else. Not only that, but it seems like it could be easily extended to prove the irrationality of any non-square natural number. It is, in essence, a proof that $\sqrt{\mathbb{N}}$ is either an integer or irrational.
The proof is as follows:
Suppose $\sqrt{2}$ is rational; it can then be expressed with two coprime integers $a$ and $b$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{2} &= \frac{a}{b} \\
    2        &= \frac{a^2}{b^2} \\
\end{align*} \\
b^2 \mid a^2 \Rightarrow b \mid a \\
$$
I believe it can be trivially proven that if $a^2/b^2$ is an integer then $a/b$ is an integer.* This forces $b=1$, meaning that $\sqrt{2}=a$ is an integer. Of course, $\sqrt{2} \notin \{1, 2\}$, so it cannot be an integer. We have arrived at a contradiction, and $\sqrt{2}$ thus must be irrational.
The only assumption I see not mentioned in the proof is that $0<\sqrt{x}\le x$ for all $x > 1$, which should also be easy to prove and not pose an issue to the proof. If this proof is indeed known and valid, please point me to a source which includes it. Thank you.

* The proof, as requested by a user:
We will prove the contrapositive (if $a/b$ is not an integer then $a^2/b^2$ is not an integer) like so:
Suppose $a^2/b^2$ is an integer. $\gcd(a, b)=1$ implies $\gcd(a^2, b^2)=1$, which forces $b^2=1$ and thus $b=1$. Yet, $a/b$ not being integer implies that $b \ne 1$. We have arrived at a contradiction.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Shaun Please be more careful not to move comments explaining the dupe closre to chat.  Generally there should be no rush to move comments unless they get really out of hand.
